# gsap draggable: elements on top stop showing as soon as drag element is clicked

Tags: javascript, draggable, gsap

I'm creating a website where the **background is draggable**. It has content on top of it that is not supposed to be dragged along with the background.

I'm using [gsap's draggable plugin](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/Draggable) for the background.

---

*index.html*

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="draggable-content">
    <img ... />
    ...
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="non-draggable-content">
    Stay where you are.
  </div>
</div>
```

*styles.css*

```css
.non-draggable-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

*main.js*

```js
Draggable.create(".draggable-content", {
  type: "x",
  bounds: document.querySelector(".main-container"),
  inertia: true,
  dragClickables: false,
  onClick: function () {
    console.log("clicked");
  },
  onDragEnd: function () {
    console.log("drag ended");
  },
});
```

---

Everything works perfectly fine when the window loads. But as soon as I click on or drag the `draggable-content`, the `non-draggable-content` stops getting displayed.

What can I do to keep the `non-draggable-content` in the same place while the elements behind change position as they are dragged?

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the elements and found that as soon as I click on the `draggable-content` div, the `z-index` goes to a very large number like 1000 or 1004.

I solved it by increasing the z-index of my `non-draggable-content` div.

```css
.non-draggable-content {
  z-index: 2000;
}
```